# Javascript ES6 Iterator protocol and forEach

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterator

Currently I am sharpening my ES6 skills a bit. I am looking into Iterator/Generator-syntax. I have a working example of

```js
class Library {
    constructor(){
        this._books = [];
    }
    addBook(book){
        this._books.push(book);
    }
    get books() {
        return this._books;
    }
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for(let i=0; i<this._books.length; i++) {
            yield this._books[i];
        }
    }
}

l = new Library();
l.addBook("Book1");
l.addBook("Book2");

for(let book of l){
    console.log(book);
}
```

Where everything works fine. But my first approach was trying something like

```
*[Symbol.iterator]() {
    this._books.forEach(
        book => yield book
    )
}
```

Which is (obviously) not correct. Is there besides looping with `for` or `while` a more concise way, to write this?

Comment: WAG, but if Array implements the iterator pattern, you could (again, WAG) `return _books.iterator()`. That's how I'd do it in C#, when wrapping a type that implements IEnumerable.

Comment: @Will What does WAG mean?

Comment: @shash678 wild-ass guess.

Comment: You have to use `yield` in a generator function, not in a non-generator function, which is what you are doing in the `forEach` callback.

Comment: Your `yield` in the non-working code is inside the *callback* to `.forEach`. That callback function is *not* a generator.

Comment: @Will How is [WAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wag) related? You really should take care of your  ass ...?

Comment: Well, tried it in a snippet, and no go :( Need to suggest it for ES7 because that's an awfully useful little hack.

Comment: Why not just `for (let book of l.books)` ?

Comment: Just more fun of "WAG", the Finnish Wiki-page I originally accidentally  linked, defined "WAG" as **w**ives **a**nd **g**irlfriends [of British football players]"  = ).

Comment: It seems `return _books[Symbol.iterator]()` *should* work, but it doesn't.  Unsure why. Devil in the implementation, I guess.

Comment: @trincot I hoped there would be a more concise way. I assumed, that the reason why it didn't work was, that syntactically yield was in the wrong place. But I hoped for something like `yield this._books.forEach` or whatever construct to avoid writing `for(let i=0 blabla` boilerplate

Comment: @Pointy I doubt, my code makes any (business) sense besides of being my playground.

Comment: Sure :) Another thing: you might consider using Symbol instances for your "private" object properties like `_books` because they're collision-proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it using [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*):

```
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield* this._books;
    }
```

Comment: I learn something almost every time I see one of your post. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Whoha. Nice! That's the sort of code, I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

<s>I believe the following would be the most idiomatic approach.</s> Please refer to trincot's answer.

```
*[Symbol.iterator]() {
    for(let book of this._books) {
        yield book;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay! Seems legit. at least nicer, than what I first tried.

Comment: trincot's answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

If you're literally passing through the iterator, you can also do

```
[Symbol.iterator]() {
  return this._books[Symbol.iterator]();
}
```

and skip needing the generator in the first place.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the point was more of playing with syntax and expressiveness of the language to get a feeling for what works in which way. I saw the Generator example and began toying around. Not that the code makes any bigger "sense" ;-)